# UISearchBar not resigning

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uisearchbar

I have a searchBar to which I set the delegate = self and to the delegate method "endEditing" wrote some actions. On the didBeginEditing I set a touchGesture to which acts as a background touch to resign the searchBar outlet. On the touch action i resign the searchBar's responder but for some reason it ends editing instead. I can tell that because it performs the actions added to the didEndEditing. What am I missing? thank you in advance..

```
-(void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
[_searchBarOut becomeFirstResponder];
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:.5 alpha:.5]];
[view1 setTag:20];
[view1 addGestureRecognizer:searchTap];
[view1 setAlpha:0];
[self.view addSubview:view1];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_searchBarOut];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{

    [view1 setAlpha:1];

    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y - 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {



}

-(void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
[searchBar endEditing:YES];

}

-(void) searchTap:(id) sender{
[_searchBarOut resignFirstResponder];
UIView *view1 = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:20];

if ([_searchBarOut isFirstResponder]){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        [view1 setAlpha:0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [view1 removeFromSuperview];

    }];
}
}

-(void) searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
[_searchBarOut resignFirstResponder];
UIView *view1 = [(UIView *) self.view viewWithTag:20];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{

    [view1 setAlpha:0];

    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [view1 removeFromSuperview];

    [self pushWithString:searchBar.text];
}];
}
```